# Am I correctly nesting arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, function, ascii, cs50

I'm currently working on an exercise to programme a Scrabble score calculator, I'm trying to build it one step at a time, but I'm stumped by what's going wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get word from player
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    
    // Calculate score
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    
    // Print score
    printf("%i\n", score1);
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // Compute and return score for string
    return POINTS[word[1] - 65];
}
```

Currently I'm just trying to make my program run with one player and one letter to test out the `compute_score` function of mapping letters to scores in the `POINTS` array. My logic for `POINTS[word[1] - 65]` is as follows: If I type in `Z`, for example, `word[1]` will equal `Z`. "Z" in ASCII is 90; 90 - 65 = 25; `POINTS[25]` is `10`.

So `POINTS[word[1] - 65]` = `POINTS[Z - 65]` = `POINTS[25]` = `10`.

However, when I run the programme, I receive an answer of `0`, so I must have messed something up, am I just missing something really obvious?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably range check the input before indexing the array, force to upper case and use the the character constant 'A' rather then 65:  `int score_index = POINTS[toupper(word[0] - 'A'];` then check `score_index < sizeof(POINTS)`.  Also `POINTS` should be `const` and may be local to `compute_score`.

Comment: Note sure what "_nesting_ arrays" means in this context.  You are not _indexing_ the array correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first character of word is `word[0]`, as the arrays in C are 0-based.

Comment: D'oh! So I guess we'll put that one in the "missing something really obvious" category. Thanks Simon!